# Usage of AlchemyAPI setCustomParameters

Tags: alchemyapi

I am trying [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/) for testing sentiment analysis.

I am able to run basic examples, however I did not get where exactly `setCustomParameters` method is used. The full package name of this method is

```
com.alchemyapi.api.AlchemyAPI_Params.setCustomParameters`
```

and it is used to set parameters. For example:

```
AlchemyAPI_TextParams conceptParams = new AlchemyAPI_TextParams();
conceptParams.setCustomParameters(?????)
```

I could not get any documentation for this API.

Please help me if somebody used this API already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at AlchemyAPI.

The `setCustomParameters` method is used to adjust undocumented or customer-specific parameters in AlchemyAPI.

You don't need to invoke this method in normal use of the SDK.

All the important functionality is exposed explicitly in the SDK (`setOutputMode`, `setSourceText`, etc.), and documented at http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/.

(Email support at alchemyapi.com if you'd like some direct assistance).